# Can't change url in "a" tag in specific span with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I want all the (urls)hrefs from `<a>` tags in specific span with class"post-body entry-content" to change to specific url, here's my code i did put it in the end of the body tag.. put it seams not working and i cant get what im doing wrong cause theres not error in console.(im very noob in Javascript)

Basically im trying to change every url in span with "adfly in front".

Here's my code:

```
function links(){
    var adfly = "http://adfDOTly/000/";
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('post-body entry-content')[0];
    var links = els.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        len = links.length;


    while( len-- ){
        links[len].href = adfly + links[len].href;
    }
}
links();
```

Here is some extra code that i have in my website that actually is working

```
//<![CDATA[
 function replaceurl(){
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        len = els.length;

    while( len-- ) {
  if (els[len].href.indexOf('#expand') > -1) {

  } else {
 els[len].href = els[len].href + "#expand";
  }

    }

  }

  function clearurl(){

   var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        len = els.length;

    while( len-- ) {
  if (els[len].href.indexOf('#expand') > -1) {
 els[len].href = els[len].href.replace('#expand','');
  } else {

  }

    }

  }






if (window.location.href.indexOf("#expand") > -1) {
$( "#main-wrapper" ).animate({'width':'984px'}, 'slow');
  $(".post-body iframe").animate({'height':'554px'},'slow');
  $("#sidebar-wrapper").hide("slow");

replaceurl();

}





$( "#expandmainwrapper2" ).click(function() {
$   ( "#sidebar-wrapper" ).show("slow");
  $( "#main-wrapper" ).animate({'width':'640px'}, 'slow');
  $(".post-body iframe").animate({'height':'360px'},'slow');
parent.location.hash = "";
clearurl();
    });


        $("#expandmainwrapper").click(function(){
          $( "#sidebar-wrapper" ).hide("slow");
            $( "#main-wrapper" ).animate({'width':'984px'}, 'slow');
  $(".post-body iframe").animate({'height':'554px'},'slow');
    parent.location.hash = "expand";
replaceurl();

            });

//]]>
```

In my website its not working and i dont know why heres my website [Websitelink](http://gtagreece.com)

Comment: Are you sure this works: `els.getElementsByTagName('a')`?

Comment: did i said im noob in js? thanks tho :D

Comment: Working fine [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/wyoarvc6/)

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla yeah, but in my website is not working why? [link](http://gtagreece.com)

Comment: You might be noob in JS, but you gave us a working code and you're not telling **how** it's not working.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function` you said there are no console errors, yet my console is screaming in red...

Comment: @Shomz yes but this is from another code.

Comment: Another code which we don't see or know anything about... How would you expect us to help?

Comment: well i have no idea what it is.. sorry,

Comment: I told you what it is - it's that `superfish` thing you're calling.

Comment: i have no idea what it is, so i deleted it but still is not working

Comment: just a note: `els.getElementsByTagName('a')` on the console on your website returns no links. Are you sure that's the selector?

Comment: @thepanuto yeap im changing the href from 'a' tag

Answer (score 1):

To get all your links, you should use:

`var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");`

Comment: You *can* call getElementsByTagName on a DOM node (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) But what's returned by `getElementsByClassName` is not a DOM node.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. Thanks! Edited the answer.

Comment: OP is taking the first element from the array which does have the getElementsByTagName method... The whole code is working, the error is somewhere else in his site... Even if it wasn't, selecting all links instead of what OP want is clearly not a solution here.

Answer (score 1):

What's returned from `getElementsByClassName` is an "array like object" which does *not* in turn have `getElementsByTagName`

Instead, try `querySelectorAll("a .post-body.entry-content")`
(note: space between `a` and `.`, no space between `body` and `.`)

And loop over those results

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: OP is taking the first element from the array which **does** have the `getElementsByTagName` method... The whole code is working, the error is somewhere else in his site.

Comment: I see. Then the way the OP has written it, it would only be editing links inside of one wrapper. Doesn't look like that's what s/he wants.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly how I understood it originally. Anyway, the issue is somewhere else now.